# Azure Data Factory Configure Repository on Devops

Tags: azure-devops, azure-active-directory, azure-data-factory

I have a new Azure Data Factory.

I have an Azure DevOps organisation. It is connected to the Azure Active Directory I'm logged into when configuring the data factory. I've checked this from Organization Settings\Azure Active Directory of the the Azure Devops website.

I'm trying to configure source control from the Data Factory Studio to a project within DevOps. I've checked that my user account is a "Project administrator" on that project.

From Data Factory Studio, I click the toolbox icon on the left menu. I click "Git configuration" under "Source control"

I'm then presented with a "Configure a repository" window. There are 3 drop-down boxes. I am able to select from the "Devops organization name" and "Project name" but "Repository name" is blank.

[image]

I know the target project has a git repo. I am able to clone it from the command line using the same account for which I'm logged into Data Factory Studio.

If I select the "Use repository link" radio button I'm prompted to enter the "Azure Devops link". When I paste this in I get the following error:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer here: [How to resolve no access in Azure Data Factory 2 to Azure DevOps Repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58026776/how-to-resolve-no-access-in-azure-data-factory-2-to-azure-devops-repository)

Needed to upgrade my "Stakeholder" devops account